# Spring as Dependency Injection Framework for Scala

Tags: spring, scala, spring-boot

for one of my projects I have to develop with Scala, I am quite experienced with Java and Spring, so my first impulse is to use Spring for Dependency Injection in Scala but I am not sure that is a good idea or not....

The code that I will write in Scala will most probably will be used in a Spring Boot 2 Application, it would be nice to inject beans that initiated in SB2 application into code I developed in Scala.

Is there any hiccups that I have to be aware of or Spring DI is totally compatible with Scala?

If Spring is not good match with Scala what do you advice to use? I read some articles suggesting to use Implicit's to handle DI or MacWire (which seems to be too much boiler plate compared to Spring's annotation based approach) or Guice (but I have no experience with it)...

Thx for answers..

Comment: I personally recommend using Play framework with guice for dependency injections ,it is real easy to use. I never used Spring, but from what I have read, it is more Javaish, not wrong just possible not the best aproach.
Anyways, if you are used to programm in Spring, give a try to Play, if you don´t like it go for the Spring.

Comment: There is many strong arguments against Spring, that weigh especially much in a community like Scala, where type safety and functional design are of such value. I would absolutely suggest using implicits - you will never have to handle atrocities like `IllegalStateException: Application failed to start`.

Comment: @posthumecaver did you ever decide whether to use spring in your Scala app dev?  if so, can you point me to any examples.

Comment: Yep, I am currently using Scala and Spring in a Spring Boot 2 application, any Spring Dependency Injection Annotation is working with Scala. I must say my application is Scala/Java hybrid, only %20 of our team has Scala knowledge, so I using Scala code some critical areas of the application and more simple tasks are developed in Java and injected to Scala as Java Facades...